# Back Button Support On Android for Cocos2d v3.x via Apportable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, apportable

As described in [Apportable Doc](http://docs.apportable.com/uikit-extensions), I have created a subclass of `UIResponder` named `AndroidButtonManager` to have support for hardware button tap events (Back, Home button tap) in my current cocos2d-iPhone v3.1 project. Here are the codes of interface and implementation files

```
AndroidButtonManager.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface AndroidButtonManager :UIResponder<UIApplicationDelegate>{

}
+(instancetype) sharedManager;
@end
```

and `AndroidButtonManager.m`

```
#import "AndroidButtonManager.h"


@implementation AndroidButtonManager
+(instancetype)sharedManager
{
    static AndroidButtonManager* sharedManager;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[self alloc]init];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}
-(instancetype)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self canBecomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return self;
}

#ifdef ANDROID
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//          OVER RIDING PARENT CLASS METHOD
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    [[AlertManager sharedManager] showAlertWithHeading:@"canBecomeFirstResponder" andMessage:@"AndroidButtonManager"];
    return YES;
}

- (void)buttonUpWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[AlertManager sharedManager] showAlertWithHeading:@"buttonUpWithEvent" andMessage:@""];
    switch (event.buttonCode)
    {
        case UIEventButtonCodeBack:
            [[AlertManager sharedManager] showAlertWithHeading:@"Back Button" andMessage:@"Home Button touched , going to transit to Menu Layer"];
            break;
        case UIEventButtonCodeMenu:{
            [[AlertManager sharedManager] showAlertWithHeading:@"Home Button" andMessage:@"Home Button touched , going to transit to Menu Layer"];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#endif
@end
```

And I am creating the shared manager in AppDelegate's `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` by

```
#ifdef ANDROID
    [AndroidButtonManager sharedManager];
#endif
```

I am getting alert from `[[AlertManager sharedManager] showAlertWithHeading:@"canBecomeFirstResponder" andMessage:@"AndroidButtonManager"];`, but the alert from `[[AlertManager sharedManager] showAlertWithHeading:@"buttonUpWithEvent" andMessage:@""];` never appears as `- (void)buttonUpWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is never called.

I have tried implementing this in `AppDelegate.m` as specified in [Apportable's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/apportable-discuss/992hX9vEdTw/oTdTnVYyir0J).Both are not working.
Is there any example project implementing back button support in Android in Cocos2d-v3.x?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh finally got it. Just need to make a category of `CCDirector` in which the button handling code will be executed. Here is the code of my `CCDirector`'s category name `CCDirector+ButtonManager`.

## Interface File `CCDirector+ButtonManager.h`

```
#import "CCDirector.h"

@interface CCDirector (ButtonManager)
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder;
@end
```

## Implementation File `CCDirector+ButtonManager.m`

```
#import "CCDirector+ButtonManager.h"

@implementation CCDirector (ButtonManager)
#ifdef APPORTABLE
- (void)buttonUpWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    switch (event.buttonCode)
    {
        case UIEventButtonCodeBack:
            // handle back button here
            [self showAlertWithHeading:@"buttonUpWithEvent" andMessage:@"BACK BUTTON"];
            break;
        case UIEventButtonCodeMenu:
            // show menu if possible.
            [self showAlertWithHeading:@"buttonUpWithEvent" andMessage:@"MENU BUTTON"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    [[AlertManager sharedManager] showAlertWithHeading:@"canBecomeFirstResponder" andMessage:@"CCDirector"];
    return YES;
}
#endif
-(void)showAlertWithHeading:(NSString*)alertHeading andMessage:(NSString*)alertMessage
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:alertHeading
                                                       message:alertMessage
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
}
@end
```

And initialize it in `AppDelegate`'s `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` by

```
#ifdef APPORTABLE
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] becomeFirstResponder];
#endif
```